# Need to add condition to rails find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

I have Event model which contains following fields

```
    string   "name"
    date     "start_at"
    date     "end_at"
    datetime "created_at"
    datetime "updated_at"
    string   "trainer"
    string   "venue"
    string   "description"
    boolean  "holy"
    integer  "nxt"
```

And I have also save holidays in the event that contains trainer as '0' so I need to find all the holidays on event table. Can expert give me some idea to implement this ?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails has dynamic finders. I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but this code should find all Events that have trainer = 0. To find one holiday use:

```
Event.find_by_trainer("0")
```

To find all, use:

```
Event.find_all_by_trainer("0")
```

Comment: Actually it will only find the first Event that matches, not all.

Comment: Oops DanneManne is correct. To get all holidays, use: Event.find_all_by_trainer("0")

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are looking for something like:

```
@events = Event.where(:trainer => "0")
```

Comment: You could explain this answer a little further, couldn't you?